# No firmware update option when trying to install CHDK on Canon SX210IS

Tags: canon, firmware, firmware-hacks, chdk

I checked the firmware version and downloaded the correct one from the website. I drag and drop the downloaded files into the root directory of a formatted card (4gb) and (8gb), eject, and put into the camera. I power it up using the review button, press menu and I don't see the option for firmware update. I got the option one time before but I don't know how it showed up and even when I updated it, the files were corrupted. any help would be great, sorry if this question is formatted weird, it's getting late and I'be been trying to install this for hours.

I should also add that I'm using a MacBook Pro running OS X 10.10.3

Comment: Are you sure you scrolled through the whole menu?

Comment: @inkista I got it last night, it was a problem with my Mac so I switched to a Windows computer and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

There are some good tips about installing CHDK on a Mac listed here :

[CHDK FAQ : Mac](http://chdk.wikia.com/wiki/FAQ/Mac)

Also, at the top of that page is a link to a utility called STICK that will do the complete install for you on a Mac, Windows, or Linux computer.